# Is there a way to change Application Availability by code on Oracle APEX 4.2.6

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to change an Application Avaiability by code in Oracle Apex 4.2.

I APEX 5 there is a apex_util.set_application_status method. Is there anything similar on Apex 4?

Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative, you could set up a verify function on the authentication scheme, and redirect the users to a particular page if some condition is true.

Comment: p.s. I believe apex_util.set_application_status was added in APEX 5.1, not 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this **undocumented, unsupported** API call for years with no problems so far:

```
wwv_flow_api.set_flow_status
  (p_flow_id             => 100
  ,p_flow_status         => 'UNAVAILABLE_URL'
  ,p_flow_status_message => 'http://www.example.com/system_unavailable.html'
  );
```

To make it available again:

```
wwv_flow_api.set_flow_status
  (p_flow_id             => 100
  ,p_flow_status         => 'AVAILABLE'
  );
```

To make the developer toolbar available:

```
wwv_flow_api.set_flow_status
  (p_flow_id             => 100
  ,p_flow_status         => 'AVAILABLE_W_EDIT_LINK'
  );
```

https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2015/07/deploying-apex-showing-an-under-maintenance-web-page/